# Distributed Arrays initialization in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia, calculation

I'm looking for help with julia programming. 
I'm a newbie in programming, and I know little about the structure of computer and programming, so please pardon me if I'm asking some stupid questions.

I have to do heavy calculation, so I wanna use parallel computing for the double for statement. The code is following:

```
using Distributed
@everywhere using DistributedArrays
addprocs(4)

function FreeSpace_2D(profile, x_prime, y_prime, d, x, y) 
   # profile is a 2D array, and x_prime and y_prime are 1D arrays. d, x, y is real numbers.
   Nx = length(x_prime)
   Ny = length(y_prime)
   array = dzeros((Nx, Ny), workers()[1:4], [1, 4])
   @distributed for i in 1:Nx
      @distributed for j in 1:Ny
         localpart(array)[i, j] = ( profile[i, j]*exp(-1im*0.5*k/d*((x-x_prime[i])^2+(y-y_prime[j])^2)) )
      end
   end

   return array 
end
```

but the code does not initialize the 'array'.

When I search internet, there are a few methods for initialization of 1D array using distributed, but they did not work on a 2D array.

I would appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four problems with your code:

- you need first to `addprocs` and then call `@everywhere`. Otherwise your `@everywhere` will be called only on the master process
- you need to synchronize `@distributed` loops by putting `@sync` macro before @distributed or provide an aggregator function that is:  `@distributed (some_func) for i in 1:1000`
- `@distributed` loop distributes code across all available workers. Hence it does not make sense to include one `@distributed` loop within another. I recommend putting `@distributed` only in front of the external loop
- you need to use a local part of your array on each worker node

Here is a sample code that I tried to make similar to your goals and that works correctly:

```
using Distributed
addprocs(4)

@everywhere using Distributed
@everywhere using DistributedArrays

a = dzeros(Int, (4, 8), workers()[1:4], [1, 4])

@sync @distributed for j in 1:8
    a_local = localpart(a)
    for i in 1:4
        a_local[i, ((j+1) % 2)+1 ] = 100j + 10i + myid() 
    end
end
```

Looking at the `Array` `a` reveals what has happened:

```
julia> a
4×8 DArray{Int64,2,Array{Int64,2}}:
 112  212  313  413  514  614  715  815
 122  222  323  423  524  624  725  825
 132  232  333  433  534  634  735  835
 142  242  343  443  544  644  745  845
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I tested your sample code, but it makes an error as follows: LoadError: TaskFailedException:
On worker 15:
BoundsError: attempt to access 0×0 Array{Int64,2} at index [1, 1]
setindex! at .\array.jl:828.....

I'm using julia 1.4.1.

Comment: This code is adds for 4 processes. Hence you should have only workers [2,3,4,5]. This means that you have run more `addprocs` commands. Note that the `Array` above is distributed only on workers 2-5 (this is what was in your code). The `@distributed` loop iterates over all workers available. Hence you need either: stick to 4 workers OR to distribute `a` across all available workers OR use  a different mechanism to distribute your workload (that use use `@spaw` to distribute the workload only to desired workers)

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. I realized the `addprocs` keeps the process number even after the program ends. Your sample code correctly works! However, in my actual code, when I used your method which indexes the column of a_local, it gives an error **LoadError: setindex! not defined for DArray{Float64,2,Array{Float64,2}}** ... although I used your indexing method exactly, **a_local[i, ((j+66)%67)+1]**. Please forgive my endless questions... 

Comment: In  my code the value type is `Int` and `DArray` stores `Int`s as well perhaps you have some value type mismatch?

Comment: I set the type of the array `dzero(ComplexF64, (Nx, Ny), ...)`. But My function which sets the array element returns `zero(ComplexF64, (Nx, Ny), ...)`. Do dzero and zero differ?

Comment: I do not uderstand your questions. Perhaps running `display(localpart(a))` would give you a better understanding what is going on. BTW another comment: if all your workers are running on a single machine use https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/SharedArrays/ instead of `DistributedArrays`. It has a simpler API and will be much faster in many scenarios.

Comment: Perhaps you are asking what `localpart` is. Think of it as a view of some part of memory that represents the part of the larger array visible to the current worker. Hence each view of a subarray has it's own numbering. `SharedArray` might be much more natural to begin working with multiprocessing in Julia.

Comment: I successfully completed my code using `ShareArray`! I really appreciate your kind feedback. Have a nice weekend!